# Wrong line spacing inside new environment

Tags: spacing, environments, line-spacing, vertical-spacing

I need a new environment with different font size, e.g. `\large`. I'm doing something like this **MWE**:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}   % dummy text
\usepackage{setspace} % for a 'forced' solution

\NewDocumentEnvironment{mynewenv}{}{\large}{}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{myotherenv}{}{\begin{spacing}{1}\large}{\end{spacing}}

\begin{document}
\begin{mynewenv}
\lipsum[1][1-4]

\lipsum[1][1-4]
\end{mynewenv}

Text outside environments and with normal size.
% 'forced' solution:
\begin{myotherenv}
\lipsum[1][1-4]

\lipsum[1][1-4]
\end{myotherenv}
\end{document}
```

which produces the **output**:
[image]

It seems that the second paragraph doesn't have the same line spacing as the first, so I assume I'm doing something wrong.

The last two paragraphs are an attempt to force a solution with the help of `setspace` package. It works fine, but as I said, I'm sure there is something I'm not doing properly and, there must be a simpler solution. Any help?

Comment: `\NewDocumentEnvironment{mynewenv}{}{\large}{\par}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at the definition of `spacing` by `setspace.sty` you see (comments removed)

```
\newenvironment{spacing}[1]{%
  \par
  \begingroup
  \setstretch {#1}%
}{%
  \restore@spacing
}
```

and now you see that

```
\newcommand{\restore@spacing}{%
  \par
  \vskip \parskip
  \vskip \baselineskip
  \endgroup
  \vskip -\parskip
  \vskip -\baselineskip
}
```

You need almost nothing from the package, except for the main thing, namely `\par` at the beginning and at the end.

```
\NewDocumentEnvironment{mynewenv}{}{\par\large}{\par}
```

What's the reason for `\par` at the end? If you don't have it, the scope of `\large` ends before a paragraph is typeset and TeX will use the baseline spacing valid when `\par` is encountered, so generally from `\normalsize`.

Comment: I knew, there must be a simple solution. Thanks for the help and the explanation!!